# Compiling simple C++ SFML file with network code using MinGW throws error "undefined reference to IpAddress"

Tags: c++, windows, mingw, sfml

I keep getting errors when compiling a C++ project using SFML 2 on Windows using MinGW.

At `C:\MinGW\include\` there is the SFML header files folder including `Network.hpp` and I also copied the `libsfml-[...].a` files into `C:\MinGW\lib\` as well as the `sfml-[...]-2.dll` files into `C:\MinGW\bin\`.

This is my sample file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SFML/System.hpp>
#include <SFML/Network.hpp>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
   {
   sf::TcpListener listener;

   listener.listen(4444);

   sf::TcpSocket client;

   std::cout << "Waiting for client to connect..." << std::endl;

   if (listener.accept(client) == sf::Socket::Done)
      {
      std::cout << "Client connected: " << client.getRemoteAddress() << std::endl;
      listener.close();
      }
   else
      {
      std::cout << "Client didnt connect" << std::endl;
      }

   return 0;
   }
```

If I try to compile it using the following command

```
g++ test.cpp -lsfml-system -lsfml-network
```

I get these errors:

```
C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Temp\cc6XzH1R.o:test.cpp:(.text+0x28): undefined reference to `_imp___ZN2sf9IpAddress3AnyE`
C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Temp\cc6XzH1R.o:test.cpp:(.text+0x3a): undefined reference to `_imp___ZN2sf11TcpListener6listenEtRKNS_9IpAddressE`
```

Thanks for any help :D
   Matze

Comment: http://www.sfml-dev.org/faq.php#build-link-static Sounds like you need to either follow these instructions, or compile with `-shared`.

Comment: @user657267 Using the `-shared` option doesnt solve the problem, the errors are the same :/

Comment: @user657267 Compiling with `g++ test.cpp -lsfml-system-s -lsfml-network-s` also results in the same errors :(

Comment: I just tried and it works without any changes, make sure you downloaded the correct version of the libraries, e.g. TDM/Mingw and 32/64 bit.

Comment: @user657267 Well okay Ill reinstall SFML then. Thanks for your help anyway :)

Comment: @user657267 Okay Im an idiot... I had the 32bit version of MinGW but the 64bit version of SFML :/ Just strange that everything else - Windows, Graphics, Sound - worked well.. Much thanks to you tho :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple , try to link correct version of library.
If you are making x86 app use the 32bit version of library and if you are making x64 app use 64bit version. I also got the same error and this fixed.